# Android handler post delayed not working perfectly with bluetooth 3.0

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-bluetooth

I have two tasks to do in my android app - Record sensor data and send messages after every x milliseconds. I use bluetooth socket to send messages to other devices and use handler to send messages after specific delay time. Everything works perfect in a device which runs android api 23.

The problem happens when I do this in a device of api 15. The device has bluetooth 3.0. When sensor data is logged, the handler doesn't follow the mentioned delay time. But if I don't log sensor data, the handler follows the mentioned delay time in sending messages.

Another point is that this works perfectly if I use wifi direct instead of bluetooth socket to send messages in api 15 device.

Why is it that handler doesn't follow the delay time to send messages using bluetooth socket if I log sensor data in a device of api 15? What could be the reasons?

In short:

1. Device with api 23 works fine in logging sensor data as well as send messages via bluetooth socket after a specific delay time.
2. Device with api 23 and 15 works fine in logging sensor data as well as send messages via wifi direct after a specific delay time.
3. Device with api 15 doesn't send messages via bluetooth after the specified delay time if sensor data is logged.

Comment: Your description makes me feel that it has nothing to do with **Handler**.Focus on your logic code or bluetooth 3.0 instead.

Comment: Yes. But there is something related to api 15 and bluetooth 3.0 which makes the handler not to post something after the delay. My guess is that CPU is doing "something" because of sensor logging and bluetooth 3.0.

Comment: Maybe you should apply the code where you do handler post.